# Access to Django ORM from remote Celery worker

Tags: django, orm, celery, distributed

I have a Django application and a Celery worker - each running on it's own server.
Currently, Django app uses SQLite to store the data.
I'd like to access the database using Django's ORM from the worker.
Unfortunately, it is not completely clear to me; thus I have some questions.

1. Is it possible without *hacks*/*workarounds*? I'd like to have a simple solution (I would not like to implement REST interface to object access). I imagine that achieving this could be done if I started using PostgreSQL instance which is accessible from both servers.
2. Which project files (there's just Django + `tasks.py` file) are required on the worker's machine?
3. Could you provide me with an example or tutorial? I tried looking it up but found just tutorials/answers bound to a problem of local Celery workers.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for ways to do this simply but... Your best option is to attached a kind of callback to the task function that will call another function on the django server to carry out the database update